# How to replace a mask group from within a component in Adobe XD?

Tags: svg, adobe-xd

I'm new to the concept of a [component](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zmk41KxgaQ) in XD, but I found it to be very powerful. Right now I would like to create a master copy of a component that is a button and contains an svg inside of it, but then on the copies of this component I would like to simply replace that svg with another one.

[image]

I would like to replace that bar with another svg in another copy of this component, but I'm not finding an easy way to do that, this happens instead:

[image]

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are safe.

Do not drag and drop the image in such case. I am not sure XD works to replace the image that existed.
Instead try this

1. Make the group inside your mask expand.
2. select the layer inside your **BAR** folder.
3. Copy and Paste your new icon here. A new layer inside the same group gets created with new icon.
4. Delete the first image that was to be replaced inside the folder.

Hope it works !

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you have made it as a component. Create it as a component (it will be master component). Then create instance (copy of that master component). So the copy (which would be child, its properties can be overridden). If you make changes to your master component it will affect all child component but if you do changes on individual child component then it will be local to that only.

[You can read more about components here](https://helpx.adobe.com/xd/help/components.html)